# Is there a way to get the second slide to start at the top of the window in Cycle2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle2

If I scroll to the bottom of the first slide (very tall image) and then click "next" the second slide is cut off at the top (or it may even be completely above the top of the window depending on the size of the window). Is there a way to make the second slide start at the top of the window?

```css
#containerPages {
  width:200px;
  height:auto;
}

#containerPages div img {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}

.external {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 180px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
<div id="containerPages">
    <div class="cycle-slideshow" 
    data-cycle-timeout=0
    data-cycle-pager="#no-template-pager"
    data-cycle-pager-template=""
    data-cycle-prev="#prev"
    data-cycle-next="#next"
    data-cycle-slides="> div"
    data-cycle-auto-height=false
    >
        <div><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/3000"></div>
        <div><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/600"></div>
    </div>
</div>
    
<div id=no-template-pager class="cycle-pager external">             
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/20/20">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/20/20"> 
    <span id=prev>&lt;&lt;Prev </span>
    <span id=next> Next&gt;&gt;</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I think I figured it out by adding some jQuery  $("span").click(function(){
              $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
        })

Comment: not user friendly having such a display. Otherwise use the event callbacks of plugin to do what you need

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl I considered that but, I think that the way in which I ultimately plan to implement this it will be ok. My code snippet was a very simplified example. I'll look into the event callbacks of the plugin as you suggested. Thanks for the tip. I'm so new to this I didn't even know where to look. Is my above solution completely off base?

Answer (score 0):

I would ideally use images of equal heights, The solution your asking for might turn out to be a cure that's worse than the disease. Try the below though.

```
var win_height = $(window).height(), scroll_pos = win_height + $(window).scrollTop();

$('window').on('scroll' , function(){
      if(win_height < scroll_pos) {
          $('#containerPages').css({'position' : 'fixed' });
      }  else {
          $('#containerPages').css({'position' : 'static' });
      }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexander Solonik, I can't get this to work just yet but I'll mess around with it some more. However, I will not be able to use a fixed position with the rest of my layout. Thanks for the warning about equal height on the images but ultimately I will be using text instead of images.  I think the usability will be ok. What do you think of my solution in the above comments? It works but is it a good way to go about this?

Comment: @NewsletterPoll somebody has already pointed out , that , your solution might be bad for UX , the user is not expecting the page to scroll to the top , and i think the same.